# My Blackmagic Atem Mini Extreme wont go “On Air.” Why?

Tags: video-streaming

I recently got a [Blackmagic Atem Mini Extreme](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/atemmini/techspecs/W-APS-17), however when I try to go live on Vimeo I just get a flashing on-air button. Eventually the cache fills up and I'm still not on air.

What can I do, I've checked network connectivity, my connection to Vimeo, it was working yesterday.

Comment: What does “it was working yesterday.” refer to? The setup? Vimeo? Something else? This is a decent self-answered question but that last bit is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this is to do with the order in which you plug things in.

The Atem can connect over USB or LAN and sometime you can have both plugged in like now when I wand to do a zoom call and stream to vimeo.  If you plug in the Ethernet cable first it will work fine.

To fix.

- Unplug Atem
- Unplug USB C
- Plug in Ethernet cable
- Plug in Power
- Plug in USB C

Should work fine now.

Ps.  I found [this question on the Blackmagic Design forum](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?t=140944&p=758724) and I tried to answer it, but you need a degree in computer mastery to even register for an account, so I gave up and went to Super User instead.

Comment: This is ridiculous, but worked. We wanted to go live with our church service and this fixed it last second  Thanks man!